# Can I substitute furnace cement for high temperature epoxy?

Tags: epoxy

I am building a project in *The Practical Pyromaniac*, and I am wondering if for the **Burning Ring of Fire**, a simple cooktop, I can substitute furnace cement for high temperature epoxy? The furnace cement would need to be as air tight as high temp epoxy, as it will be used to keep burning gas in an inner chamber.

Comment: Depends - what temperature do you expect to reach, directly or indirectly, at the surface of the cement/epoxy? Through conduction, convection, radiation? How long do you need it to last? Without knowing some specifics, it's really hard to tell. Wait - the original spec calls for EPOXY and you want to substitute WITH furnace cement? Is there a structural reason for the epoxy? Furnace cement will certainly withstand any temperature that can be withstood by any epoxy, but it may not be structurally as strong.

Comment: For this stove, the intent of the furnace cement is two-fold: it is used to provide a heavy bodied, insulating block at the bottom of the "two-can" fuel chamber assembly which absorbs the heat and prevents distortion of the metal; it also provides the seal which contains the alcohol fuel inside the inner can.

Comment: The epoxy for gluing the fuel-filler port nut cannot be substituted with furnace cement, the heat-cycling will cause the furnace cement to crack and crumble.

Comment: @ Jimmy Fix-it Thank you for your research! if you would combine your last two comments into an answer there is a high chance you will get the bounty. I can't award a bounty to a comment though. :)